# Add index number to list of results of `Select-String`

Tags: powershell, select-string, select-object

I need to search for a term in a file and display an index in the search results so that referencing is easy.

The command in bash would be:

`cat <file> | grep 'Table: ' | cat -n`

What I have so far in Powershell:

`Get-Content <file> | Select-String 'Table: ' | Select-Object -Property LineNumber, Line`

Unfortunately, I didn't realize that `LineNumber` gives the actual line in the file and not the index in the results list.

How can I translate the bash command into its Powershell equivalent?

Comment: We can do this in bash in powershell. `cat <file> | grep 'Table: ' | cat -n`. `get-content <file> | select-string 'Table: ' | (foreach ($line in $(Get-Content -Path test.sh)){$count++; echo "$count $line"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the `.Line` property of the objects output by `Select-Object` indicates the line number of each match in a given input file.

PowerShell has no direct equivalent of `cat -n` (prepending a `1`-based index to all input lines on output), but it's not hard to roll your own using the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) cmdlet:

```
$i = 0
Get-Content file.txt | Select-String 'Table: ' | ForEach-Object {
  "{0,6}`t{1}" -f ++$i, $_.Line
}
```

The above uses `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), to left-space-pad to 6 characters (`,6`) the first RHS operand (`{0}`), which is the (incremented) index, `++$i`, followed by a tab character (`` `t ``) and the second RHS operand (`{1}`), which is the input line at hand (`$_.Line`).

Answer (score 0):

Just use WSL:

```
bash -c "cat <file> | grep 'Table: ' | cat -n"
```

This will run the bash code in powershell. For a true powershell option you could do this:

```
foreach ($line in $(Get-Content -Path <filepath> | Select-String 'Table: ')){
  $count++
  echo "$count $line"
}
```